In modelling is there a way to avoid a triangle where limbs meet torso?
in teaching myself how to build a human figure from a cube (following the guidance of several YouTube videos) I've noticed they end up with areas where arms and legs meet the torso at a triangular point. I realize this isn't quite the same as "tri's" but would a model like this have rigging issues?
Thanks!
Michael


It's not clear what kind of problem you are thinking about, that said, whatever your topology is, you need to consider what you want to do afterwards, how you want to animate this mesh, will it deform and bend correctly, etc. If you want to avoid these "triangles" for some reason, on the groin area you can create a gap with this topology, as for the armpits, it's generally better to have a T pose like this:


Thank you so much for your answer! My objective is to build very low poly figures with fairly realistic proportions that I can then rig and animate. I've tried the "extrude a cube" method as well as skin modifiers but the method as depicted in the image you shared seems to avoid the pitfalls of e-poles/tris/n-gons. Thank you again for taking the time to help me out!
